# Set Owner+Access-rights with io.open

Tags: ios, lua, permissions, owner

In a lua-script (for Domoticz @ Raspberry) I apply the following script-segment to generate an htm-file and to put it in the designated folder.

Line02text till Line30text are variables which are dynamically filled elsewhere in the lua-script.

```
file = io.open("/home/pi/domoticz/scripts/lua/XXXXX.htm", "w+")
-- Opens a file named XXXXX.htm (stored under the designated sub-folder of Domoticz)
-- in append mode
-- write lines to opened file
file:write("SOF<br>")
file:write(Line02text .. "<br>")
file:write(Line03text .. "<br>")

....

file:write(Line29text .. "<br>")
file:write(Line30text .. "<br>")
file:write("EOF<br>")
file:close() -- closes the open file
```

All seems OK, because the htm-file appears as planned.

Next steps would be to copy the file to different folder, open in browser, etc..

But Owner of the htm-file is 'root' and Permission is 0640.

For further application Owner should be different, and Permission e.g. 777.

Trying manual change or use of chmod results in report 'Permission denied' by server.

**Question:** 
How to set (as result of the lua-script) different Owner and other Permission for the htm-file?

Comment: Can you insert the line `os.execute("chmod a+rw /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/lua/XXXXX.htm")` after `file:close()` ?

Comment: Thanks Egor!
The addition of that scriptline is the solution to get a file which can be accessed by all users.

Answer (score 0):

Lua's target is to be as portable as possible, and ownership/permissions management is very os-specific. There's no embedded functions to handle that.

You'll need to expose some native function that will do what you need with files' permissions. Or use some already existing library for that, like maybe `lua-fs`: (https://github.com/clementfarabet/lua-fs-0.3)